# problema con almacenar el contenido a una varible en una funcion en tkinter

Tags: python, funciones

tengo un problema y es que tengo un programa con un boton "Examinar" para seleccionar la ruta de una carpeta y la guarda en una varible dentro de una función tal que así:

```
def Examinar():
    Ejemplo = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if Ejemplo!="":
        os.chdir(Ejemplo)
    file_source = str(os.getcwd())
```

Mi problema viene que necesito usar el contenido de esta varible en otra función para iniciar el programa, tal que así:

```
def CarpetaPrint():
        for g in elementos2:
            shutil.copy(file_source + g, file_destination)
```

Pero no puedo usar "file_source" no se porque, alguien me ayuda? gracias.

Comment: ... Ve en el tutorial que estas haciendo del programar en python sobre las variables locales y variable globales

Comment: @DanielBriceño Buenas, he estado viendo que se puede declarando como global la varible file_source, pero también he visto que hace que el codigo sea menos legible para otras personas, etc. Es eso cierto? saludos

Comment: No, la declaración global hace menos legible el código para los que no conocen el lenguaje, pues si hiciera menos legible el código los desarrolladores python eliminarian esa declaración del lenguaje.

Comment: Si no quieres usar variables globales también puedes usar la declaración [return](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-funciones-2.html#:~:text=La%20instrucci%C3%B3n%20return%20indica%20el,la%20llamada%20a%20la%20funci%C3%B3n.&text=Se%20ejecuta%20la%20%C3%BAltima%20instrucci%C3%B3n%20del%20programa%20y%20el%20programa%20termina.) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `return` para devolver el valor que necesites, en este caso:

```
def Examinar():
    Ejemplo = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if Ejemplo!="":
      os.chdir(Ejemplo)
    file_source = str(os.getcwd())
    return file_source
```

Y en el siguiente paso, llama a la función donde la necesites:

```
def CarpetaPrint():
        for g in elementos2:
            shutil.copy(Examinar() + g, file_destination)
```